# Unable to restart NetworkManager

Tags: boot, network-manager, fsck

ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Kernel 4.15.0-135-generic

On a dualboot laptop, normal boot was stopped because of an error message that said to run ckfs. I did it but since then, I can't connect to the wifi network. Th pc boots seemingly normally but something is blocking NetworkManager from starting.

I tried rebooting, and restart NetworkManager with:

```
[sudo]frepie@frepie-K55N:/var/log$ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
[sudo] password for frepie: 
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
frepie@frepie-K55N:/var/log$
```

I ran a few tests. Here are the results:

NetworkManager:

```
frepie@frepie-K55N:/var/log$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-21 06:36:43 EST; 2min 36s ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
  Process: 27872 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27872 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 06:36:43 frepie-K55N systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

journalctl -xe:

```
frepie@frepie-K55N:/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services$ sudo journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Feb 21 07:52:06 frepie-K55N sudo[28881]:   frepie : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status Netw
Feb 21 07:52:06 frepie-K55N sudo[28881]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 07:52:06 frepie-K55N sudo[28881]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N sudo[28891]:   frepie : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl journalctl 
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N sudo[28891]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one gi
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N rsyslogd[925]: action 'action 1' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Sun Feb 21 07:53:13 2021, retry nbr 0.
Feb 21 07:52:43 frepie-K55N sudo[28891]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 21 07:52:59 frepie-K55N sudo[28895]:   frepie : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Feb 21 07:52:59 frepie-K55N sudo[28895]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

As requested by Deepak Reddy

```
Mar 06 08:21:20 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615036880.4374] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mar 06 08:21:20 frepie-K55N dhclient[1139]: bound to 192.168.1.110 -- renewal in 35851 seconds.
Mar 06 13:22:29 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615054949.3635] connectivity: (enp5s0) timed out
Mar 06 13:22:54 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <warn>  [1615054974.3071] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1451/status”: No such file or directory
Mar 06 13:22:54 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <warn>  [1615054974.3095] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1451/status”: No such file or directory
Mar 06 13:22:54 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <warn>  [1615054974.3103] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: Failed to open file “/proc/1451/status”: No such file or directory
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1172] device (enp5s0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1346] dhcp4 (enp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1139
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1347] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed bound -> done
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1352] dhcp6 (enp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1449] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 06 13:25:05 frepie-K55N NetworkManager[928]: <info>  [1615055105.1451] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

Error in reinstalling network manager:

```
frepie@frepie-K55N:~$ sudo apt --reinstall install network-manager
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_InRelease (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
frepie@frepie-K55N:~$
```

As suggested by   , I removed all xenial references in the update file and run the update command but got the fallowing error message:

```
frepie@frepie-K55N:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for frepie: 
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB] ...
```

...

```
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
Fetched 15.0 MB in 10s (1,582 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Ok I managed to correct the issue

After receiving the error  "Problem with Mergelist /var/lib/dpkg/status, I applied a solution that suggested to go fetch an older version of the file "status" in lib/dpkg folder where several older versions of that files are stored periodically. I chose one fairly recent but not too recent so it wouldn't have the same problem as the actual one.

So I extracted the older version, moved it in the proper folder then renamed the actual file then renamed the old file properly

```
sudo gunzip dpkg.status.6.gz
sudo mv dpkg.status.6 /var/lib/dpkg/status.arch
cd /var/lib/dpkg
sudo cp status.arch status
```

Then I update and tried to upgrade. Upgrading was causing the following error:

```
files list file for package 'wpasupplicant' contains empty filename
```

So I followed the instructions in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094737/apt-get-fails-with-following-error-linux-headers-3-2-0-58-generic-contains-empt#39359088

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm wpasupplicant.list
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

After the update and upgrade, the original issue was corrected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate how you are trying to get NM to restart and your Ubuntu version.

Comment: It is always good that you post feedback on the solutions suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn’t seem to be any reason for the failure based on what you’ve posted, so let’s see if we can restart it. In Terminal, try this:

```
sudo service network-manager force-reload
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If that doesn’t work, then let’s see if a reinstallation will work:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install network-manager
```

This generally works best if you can plug the notebook into the network with an Ethernet cable but, if you can’t and `apt` gives you a “Failed to fetch files” error, you can [download the `.deb` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/net/network-manager) (probably from a different computer) and install it like this:

```
sudo dpkg -i <name of deb package file>
```

Hopefully this will result in a properly-working network manager service

Comment: See top for results

Comment: The source shows as being `xenial`, but you said that you’re running 18.04, which is `bionic`. If you are running 18.04 then you’ll need to remove all `xenial` references from your Apt sources list, update Apt, then try again 

Comment: And how is this done? I have no idea how xenial apt ended up there.

Comment: You can do this in the "Software & Updates" application settings. Make sure the "Sources" do not have any checkmarks next to items saying `xenial`. Then you should be able to re-install Network Manager. If you prefer the commandline, `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, and comment out the lines with `xenial` by putting a `#` at the start of the line. Then `sudo apt update` and install 

Comment: I did what you suggested but got an error message when trying to update. See post for details

Comment: After reading through the issues, it was good to see that you managed to resolve it in the end 

Answer (score 0):

mine also sometimes gets stuck for (to me) unknown reason.
when:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

doesn't help, then i found that on my 18.04.5 LTS with 4.14.0-135-generic this can* help:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

if it doesn't, then i reboot.

(* note that it doesn't seem to work on my other machine with 20.04.2 LTS and 5.8.0-44-generic.)

Comment: Did both without any effect

Comment: yes, got it again few days ago and nothing worked so had to reboot. [on 18.4.06 LTS and 4.15.0-206-generic]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the more debug info `systemctl status` and `journal xe` is not saying much.
Try  to restart and paste `journalctl -u NetworkManager -f  -n100` output.

Comment: I pasted your request. Please note that at first , the computer was connected to a network cable and network worked fine. This shows on the first few lines of the output.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Pop!OS) I had to use

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

because as `network-manager.service` didn't exist.